# How to exclude trashed contacts from CiviReports

Tags: civireport

I am just getting my feet wet with CiviReports using a basic CiviReport template to create a snapshot of our membership by categories. Simple enough, but the counts on almost each category were slightly different from what we had obtained in an export for a postal mailing using the same criteria. A bit of investigation showed that the difference between the higher total in the Civireport and the lower total of the export is exactly the number of contacts in Trash. Is it possible that membership CiviReport counts are including trashed records? If so, how does one exclude them (apart from emptying the trash, which we weren't ready to do). I don't see anything on the template that allows me to exclude trash. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a [bug](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20545) with a recent not-yet-published [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11136)